# How to use row_number() to filter duplicates with multiple joins?

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, row-number

I need to filter duplicates in base of other column. This is the code I am trying. Unfortunately, it doesn't work as the query never finish.

```
Select r1, r2, r3...,rb1,..., rc1,...  
From (
  Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r1 order by r6 DESC) AS rownbr  
  From
    table1
    join table2 ON r2=rb1  
    Join table3 ON r6=rc1  
    Join table4 ON rx=rdx
) source  
Where  
  rownbr=1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please expand on 'doesn't work', then maybe someone will have some ideas

Comment: The query never finish. thanks, Nick!

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it? That would make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: My guess is that your joins are incorrect, therefore you get way too many records as well as 'duplicates'. Are you absolutely certain your joins are correct? You should also alias all column names. What table is r1 and r6 out of? why don't you pre-summarise this table so you don't 'underjoin' in the first place?

Comment: When I run the code without the "row_number() over() partition()" works perfectly. the problem arises when I use row_number(). with a distinct clause, I can avoid most of the duplicates, but there are some duplicates that are not equal in every column for a reason. these are the ones I need to avoid.

Comment: could you send me some information about how to pre-summarise the table?

Comment: many thanks again Nick!

Comment: There is no `distinct` in your query. You need to explain the whole story and what actual query you are. You also need to explain how many rows are in each table and what the primary key is in each table. There's no magic answer here - you have to understand the tables.

Comment: Hi nick! thanks again for your help. Please, check my last answer when you have a chance is more detailed just in case you have any tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntactically, you seem to have got the query correct. However, in joining with 4 tables without any `where` clause you may be trying to retrieve way too much data. A couple of easy things that could improve the query would be:

- only specify the columns that you need in the subquery. I'm pretty sure you don't need everything from all 4 tables.
- find out if you can be more specific with the data you are trying to fetch and use it in the `where` clause. For instance, you may only want data where `t1.createdate > '01-01-2016'`
- if these still don't help, you will have to start looking into indexes.

```sql
    Select r1, r2, r3,rb1  
    From (
      Select * -- consider specifying only the columns that you need. Pretty sure you don't need every column from all 4 tables.
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r1 order by r6 DESC) AS rownbr  
      From table1 as t1
        join table2 as t2 ON t1.r2 = t2.rb1  
        Join table3 as t3 ON t3.r6 = t2.rc1  
        Join table4 as t4 ON t4.rx = t3.rdx
        where --may be something like date
        t1.createdate > '01-01-2016'
    ) source  
    Where  source.rownbr=1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
you are right I am just using the columns from the first join. I am not very familiar with this method. Can I use something like this?
``Select r1, r2, r3...,rb1,..., rc1,...   
From (  
  Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r1 order by r6   DESC) AS rownbr    
  From  
    table1  
    join table2 ON r2=rb1) source  
FROM???  
    Join table3 ON r6=rc1    
    Join table 4 ON rx=rdx  
Where    
  rownbr=1``

Comment: Well it is difficult for me to tell how much it will help without knowing your tables and relationship between them. The point I am trying to emphasize, since you said the query doesn't complete, is to be specific and only retrieve necessary data. Are you really interested in all the data from the table1, you don't have any eligible where clause? How many rows are there in the table1, table2, table3, and table4?

Comment: I will try to use just some attributes as you said! I will let you know! many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't add a comment yet...

Assuming your joins are correct, why not just use group by?

```
    Select r1, r2, r3...,rb1,..., rc1,...  
From (
  Select *
  From
    table1
    join table2 ON r2=rb1  
    Join table3 ON r6=rc1  
    Join table 4 ON rx=rdx
) source  
group by r1, r2, r3...,rb1,..., rc1,...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Jay! I will have a go with this ASAP!

Comment: The problem with group by is that I need to work with a lot of columns.

Comment: The problem was that I was working with way too much data, so I have used a where clause from the FROM clause. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: GROUP BY is not good for finding, or deleting duplicates. It will lose some of the data from the resultant table. It is a slow process too. You can learn about four types of methods to remove duplicates. https://www.sqlshack.com/different-ways-to-sql-delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-sql-table/

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution creating a view:

```
CREATE VIEW TABLAEX
AS
select lastname, convert(varchar, birthdate, 103) "birthday",
CONVERT(varchar, hiredate, 103) "hiredate", city,  
(DATEDIFF(dd, birthdate, hiredate) + 1)   
-(DATEDIFF(wk, birthdate, hiredate) * 2)  
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, birthdate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, hiredate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) "working days",  
 case when city like '%London%' then 'vecino'  
 when city like '%Seattle%' then 'lejos'  
 else 'null'  
 end as val,   
 case when (DATEDIFF(dd, birthdate, hiredate) + 1)  
 -(DATEDIFF(wk, birthdate, hiredate) * 2)  
 -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, birthdate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  
 -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, hiredate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 8000    then 'viejo'  
 else 'joven'  
 end as edad,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city order by hiredate) AS rownbr
 from   
 HR.Employees;
 GO
 SELECT DISTINCT lastname, birthday, hiredate, "working days", edad, val
 from TABLAEX
 WHERE rownbr=1;
 GO 
 DROP VIEW TABLAEX;
```